# How to make use of embed blocks within a for loop?

Tags: loops, twig, embed, block

I'm attempting to avoid duplication of common code by leveraging embeds within a for loop. The issue I am having is that the **{% block %}** coming from the embed is not rendering **{{ newsArticle.title }}**. If I take embed out of the equation it renders fine, but as mentioned I'd like to avoid repetition where possible.

Potentially not possible?
[Twig embed block not working when its within a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772668/twig-embed-block-not-working-when-its-within-a-loop)

Or a more suitable approach recommended?

### Reduced Example

**Embed - c-widget--image-text.twig**

```
<!-- More Markup -->

<h2><a href="#">{% block h_text %}Heading Text{% endblock %}</a></h2>

<!-- More Markup -->
```

**View & Loop**

```
{% use "../data/d-news.twig" %}

{% block content_main %}
  {% for newsArticle in newsArticles %}
    {% embed 'components/c-widgets/c-widget--image-text.twig' %}
      {% block h_text %}
        {{ newsArticle.title }}
      {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Data - d-news.twig**

```
{% set newsArticles = {

  newsArticle01: {
    title: 'News Title 01',
    slug: '',
    date: '',
    image: {
      listing: ''
    }
  },
  newsArticle02: {
    title: 'News Title 02',
    slug: '',
    date: '',
    image: {
      listing: ''
    }
  }
} %}
```

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/io2av0)

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee. You're fiddle helped in diagnosing the issue. It seems related to older versions of twig (in this case "twig": "~0.9.5").